# primary table joined to foreign table - select only one record from foreign table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2012. I have a table called deals that contains a primary key called deal_id along with 10 other fields. I also have a table called deals_country that contain a foreign key called deal_id.

It's possible that a record in deals contains numerous records in deals country. I know the query below will return all the records for the two tables.

```
select deals .*, deals_country.* from deals  inner join deals_country
on deals .deal_id = deals_country.deal_id
order by deals .deal_id
```

What I would like to do is select all the records from deals and select only one corresponding record from the deals_country table, it doesn't matter which record it takes from deals_country. Something like below,

```
Deals 
deal_id       other fields 
MN13                   
MN14                   
MN15                 
MN28       

Deals_Country
deal_id     country
MN13     NL
MN13     FR
MN14     GB
MN14     US
MN15     US
MN28     CA
MN28     US
MN28     MX
```

The result I would like see,

```
deal_id       country 
MN13          NL
MN14          GB       
MN15          US       
MN28          CA
```

Comment: Do you want in mysql or sql-server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cross apply` for this:

```
select d.*, dc.*
from deals d cross apply
     (select top 1 dc.*
      from deals_country dc
      where d.deal_id = dc.deal_id
     ) dc
order by d.deal_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate the deals_country rows per deal and select the first (whatever that is):

```
select ...
from (
    select ...
         , row_number() over (partition by deals.deal_id) as rn 
    from deals  
    join deals_country
        on deals.deal_id = deals_country.deal_id
) as T
where rn = 1;
```

Untested, but you should get the idea